# Sublime indentation on per file basis

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, indentation

Using Sublime Text 3. When opening files, some of them have indentation of 2 spaces (while the majority have 4 spaces).

Is there any way to set indentation on per file basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In menu select `View` » `Indentation` » `Tab Width: 2` to set indentation to 2 spaces for the opened file only. Next time you reopen this file Sublime Text guesses the indentation if it is 2 or 4 spaces based on the indentation found in the specific file.

> **Note:** This can technically only work with spaces as indentation. If tabs are used as indentation there is no way to set the tab width on a per file basis, but on a [per file type basis](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file-type-preferences).